# Reading the last chunk of a file open for un-cached direct I/O doesn't produce EOF, normal behavior?

Tags: c, winapi, file-io, io, memory-alignment

I'm opening a file using `CreateFile()` with the flags `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH` for several reasons, and I've noticed a strange behavior:

Since for using those flags we have to allocate memory aligned to the sector size, let's say the sector size is 512.

Now, if I allocate 512 bytes with `_aligned_malloc()` and I read from the file, everything works fine if the file size is exactly a multiple of the sector size, let's say 512*4, or 2048. I read pieces of 512 bytes and the last piece makes `ReadFile()` to return the EOF code, that is, to return `FALSE` and `GetLastError()` set as `ERROR_HANDLE_EOF`.

The problem arise when the file size it not aligned to the sector size, that is, the file's size is let's say 2048+13, or 2061 bytes.

I can successfully read the first 4 512-sized chunks from the file, and a 5th call to `ReadFile()` lets me to read the latest 13 surplus bytes from the file, but this is the strange thing: in such a case `ReadFile()` doesn't return the EOF code! Even if I told to `ReadFile()` to read 512 bytes, and it read only 13 bytes (so it surpassed the end of file), it doesn't tell me that, and returns just 13 bytes read, without no other further information.

So, when I read the last 13 bytes and my loop is set to read until EOF, it will call `ReadFile()` again for a 6th time, causing an error: `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` and I guess this is correct, because I'm trying to read after I had surpassed the end of file!

My question is: is this a normal behavior or am I doing something wrong? When using non-buffered I/O, I should expect to not having EOF code when I read the last non-sector-aligned chunk of file? Or there is another way to do that?
How I can understand that I've just passed the EOF?
I guess that I could solve this problem by modifying the loop: instead of reading until EOF, I could read until EOF *OR* until the actually returned bytes are less than the requested bytes for the reading. Is this a correct assumption?

NOTE: this *does not* happen when using files with normal flags, it only happens when I use `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` and `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`.

NOTE 2: I'm using I/O Completion Ports for reading files, but I guess this happens also without using them, by just using blocking I/O.

Comment: You should just be getting nNumberOfBytesToRead = 0 on the last read, no? This is the standard behavior for basically all files and streams on all platforms that I know of.

Comment: No. The last read should return 13 bytes read plus ERROR_HANDLE_EOF, but it just returns 13 bytes read, which is < 512, and *that* means you're EOF.

Comment: You can issue another read after that which will read 0 bytes. This is the standard pattern to drain streams because some streams/devices return less bytes than you requested even if more are available. Sockets do that for example. You don't need to check for EOF at all. Simplifies things.

Comment: Note that the documentation for ReadFile only mentions EOF in the context of asynchronous I/O.  So your second note might not be true; the behaviour may be different between the synchronous and asynchronous cases.  The comments suggest this may be the case, though there's some dispute. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EOF is surprisingly hard. Even C's `feof` function is often misunderstood.

Basically, you get `ERROR_HANDLE_EOF` in the first case to distinguish the "512 bytes read, more to read" and "512 bytes read, nothing left" cases.

In the seconds case, this is not needed. "512 bytes requested, 13 bytes read, no error" already means that you're at EOF. Any other reason for a partial read would have been an error.

Comment: Does the call to read the last sector of the file (in the first case) really report a failure even though it succeeded?  That seems odd - though IIRC it might explain a problem I had with some of my code several years back.

Comment: @Harry: Apparently. Not that it really matters to well-written code.

Comment: There is a sentence in the documentation that is probably meant to explain this, but it isn't very clear.  It wouldn't have (and apparently didn't) occur to me that reading to *exactly* the end of the file (or device) might result in an error condition, or that the data might actually have been read despite the call returning an error.  Note that it isn't documented whether `lpNumberOfBytesRead` is meaningful or not when an error occurs, though I guess it must be, otherwise this wouldn't work.